# Making dynamic MdBootstrap cards the same height

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, mdbootstrap

I am trying to make these cards the same height no matter how long the title of the movie is. The cards are dynamically created and I am also using swiperjs as the carousel. These are mdBootstrap cards just to clarify. Here is my code.

```
 <div class="swiper-container">
     <div class="swiper-wrapper trending_movies">
         <!-- dynamic cards go here -->
         <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="icon-button">
                    <ion-icon name="ellipsis-horizontal-circle-sharp" class="ion-icon" 
                    data-movie="${el.title}"></ion-icon>
                </div>
                <a href="${`/client/views/movies.html?movieId=${el.id}&movie=${el.title}`}" data-src="${el.id}" >
                     <img class="img-size" src="${poster_image}" alt="${el.title}">
                </a>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h6 class="card-title"> ${el.title}</h6>
                    <p>${el.release_date}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

[image: Here are the cards inside a swiperjs container]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this property in you CSS file like this other wise gave margin to your p tag to control this issue.

```css
  .card-body{
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
```